# Can i rederect user to Samsung app store from my android app?

Tags: android, android-intent

In my app i have to redirect user to samsung app store like.I know how to do it for google play store the link is

```
Intent browserIntent = new Intent("android.intent.action.VIEW",
                        Uri.parse("https://market.android.com/details?id=com.myPackageName"));
                startActivity(browserIntent);
```

So my question is how i can achieve this for samsung app store?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Please download the Interworking Guide from the page

http://developer.samsung.com/android/technical-docs/Samsung-Apps-Deeplink-Guide

For all the different possibilities to connect to Samsung App Store.

**Update**

Link has expired, but the answer here will have more info for the same
[Another answer on Stackoverflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10342327/does-samsung-apps-support-a-uri-scheme-to-redirect-to-specific-apps)